# WCF Web Api with HTTPS

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-2, wcf-web-api

Just to put some context.
ASP.NET MVC2
Web API 5
IIS 7

I am trying to use the WCF Web API and as soon as I enable HTTPS, it stop working.

Things I noticed:
My API call I do through jquery, and I have something like this as the url:
http://www.domain.com/api/serviceApi/SetForeignToken?token=ASDAS-ASDAS-ASDASD-ASDASDAS&foreignToken=AS123ASD

When I use the API test UI I through:
https://www.domain.com/api/serviceApi/Test
I see for the test url:
https://devserver.ad.domain.com/api/serviceapi/SetForeignToken?token=ASDAS-ASDAS-ASDASD-ASDASDAS&foreignToken=AS123ASD
It just seems od the it resolves the DNS to the machine name instead of keeping the normal DNS, as it did before without HTTPS.

Does anyone know how to configure the API to make this work unde HTTPS, or is it even possible?

Thanks,

PS. The Development Enviroment has a self-signed certificate while the production will have a real certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, WCF Web API supports HTTPS.  I believe there are a couple of ways to do this (including a code option).  I only wanted https enabled on one server so I did this in my web.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
        <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
            <add prefix="https://subdomain.example.com"/>
        </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding>
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Should I drop the default <behaviors> node, that gets created when you add the nuget package?

Comment: I am starting to think there is a problem with my DNS, and/or AD, If I put exactly what you have there, I get a "Aborted" error. If I change the Transport to none, then it works, but I basically have the same behavior as described above, where the URL gets resolved with the local machine name, and then it fails.

Comment: I am marking as an answer, but I am not sure this resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. spent whole day figuring out this. Just added the code in web.config and it worked.